# jQuery click() と .on("click") の使い分け

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(a)
$("p").click(function () {
  alert('click1');
});

(b)
$("p").on("click", function () {
  alert('click2');
});
```

(a) と (b) の動作はどちらも同じだと思いますが、内部的な処理に違いはあるのでしょうか。

・処理効率
・メモリ使用量
などそれぞれにメリット、デメリットがありましたら教えてください。

動的に追加される要素には `on()`、追加されない要素には `click()` という使い分けをしたほうが良いのか、すべてのイベント処理は `on()` で統一したほうが良いのか迷っています。

皆さんは、どのようなルールで使い分けていますか？

Comment: 本家SOに同様の質問があるのでこちらも見てみるといいかもしれません。 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

両者は同じです.

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler )
>   [.click() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

aliasは起動時に構築されているため,処理速度も変わらないと思います.

> [jquery/alias.js at 2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce · jquery/jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2d4f53416e5f74fa98e0c1d66b6f3c285a12f0ce/src/event/alias.js)

私なら静的チェックが楽なメソッドのclickを使うと思いますが,好みの問題レベルだと思います.
ただ`off`を使うなら対称性を考えて`on`の方が心地よいかもしれません.